# Laravel eloquent Query order by DESC of Time field with AM/PM

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

[image]

I try like this "TimeModel::where('deleted', 0)->orderBy(DB::raw(STR_TO_DATE('appointment_time','%l:%i %p')))->get();" but didn't work.

Please help me.

Comment: Does  `appoinment time` column define as `DATE`, `DATETIME`, `TIMESTAMP` ?

Comment: Can u try this: `orderBy(DB::raw("FORMAT(@appointment_time, 'hh:mm tt')"))`

Answer (score 2):

Make sure appointment_time is in format('g:i A')

then you can orderby using this

```
YourModel::orderByRaw("DATE_FORMAT(column_name, '%p') DESC")->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

First use DB facade,

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
```

Then,

```
addSelect(DB::raw('TIME_FORMAT(appointment_time,"%H:%i") as apt_time'))->orderBy('apt_time','DESC');
```